# Facing Issue on doing div component side by side in React

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-form-helper

`The problem is , i want to do two components side by side .
i'm using bootstrap not react bootstrap, i'm trying to do side by side as shown in image, but listgroup is coming sown of address form[image]

I tried it by css but it could not work for me , so i'm expecting listgroup to right of my address form.

Here is my code images.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
`

Comment: Please include code as text and not image :) It's easier for us to read, edit and try ourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you can do to place components side by side in a page.

Suppose you have two components `<Form/>` and `<ListGroup/>`. You should create a parent container and make it a flex container. Then wrap the components inside a `<div/>`. Code below:

```
<div style={{display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-between"}}>
   <div> 
      <Form /> 
   </div> 
   <div> 
      <ListGroup/> 
   </div> 
</div>
```

You can also give `flexBasis: some value in percentage` to the children `<div>` above to say how much screen width each component should occupy.

Update: (using flexBasis)

```
<div style={{display: "flex", flexDirection: "row"}}>
   <div style={{flexBasis: "50%"}}> 
      <Form /> 
   </div> 
   <div style={{flexBasis: "50%"}}> 
      <ListGroup/> 
   </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: it is showing the result right but taking no width.

Comment: As mentioned above in my answer, you can assign flexBasis to the div above your component. See the update in my answer will put the code.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is happening because of using multiple div, using one div, and using the flex command or checking if this happening for import error.

Answer (score -1):

Enclose them in one div and use flex for that

Comment: Can you show me a sample please?

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.flex-container > div {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  color: white;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Flexible Items</h1>

<div class="flex-container" style={{}}>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div> 
  <div>4</div>
</div>

<p>All direct children of a flexible container becomes flexible items.</p>

</body>
</html>`